# Wait for process.kill to terminate the process

Tags: node.js

My application terminates a process (exe file) then attempts to replace it with an updated version, I'm using `process.kill` with the pid of the process, I keep getting an error when trying to replace it with a newer version because the exe file is still in use and cannot be deleted, I have "resolved" this by waiting for 500ms but I wouldn't call that a good solution, I was expecting the method to be synchronous or at least have a sync counterpart just like the rest of fs methods.

Are there any other ways to do it in node.js?

Comment: I believe the only way to know if the process is actually killed is to subscribe to OS events. How Node.js is supposed to know that the OS is actually freed the resources for the process so it is available for manipulations like removing it?

Answer (score 3):

The docs says the following :

> Even though the name of this function is `process.kill()`, it is really just a signal sender, like the kill system call. The signal sent may do something other than kill the target process.

To me, it implies that `process.kill` will not indicate that the process is killed, but just that the signal has been sent (when it returns).

But there's another interesting line :

> This method will throw an error if the target pid does not exist. As a special case, a signal of 0 can be used to test for the existence of a process. Windows platforms will throw an error if the pid is used to kill a process group.

So you can come up with something like that :

```
const killProcess = ({pid, signal = 'SIGTERM', timeout} = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  process.kill(pid, signal);
  let count = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    try {
      process.kill(pid, 0);
    } catch (e) {
      // the process does not exists anymore
      resolve();
    }
    if ((count += 100) > timeout) {
      reject(new Error("Timeout process kill"))
    }
  }, 100)
})
```